# Catch C++ exception over VCL exception routine

Tags: c++, exception, c++builder, vcl

I would like to handle of all the C++ exceptions with C++ Builder to generate a crash report that could help me to debug applications when they are installed and used at the clients' places.

I tried to use the function SetUnhandledExceptionFilter but it does not work cause the VCL intercepts the exceptions and does not throw them again.

So I tried this, it doesn't work as well:

```
unsigned int Filter( unsigned int uiExCode, EXCEPTION_POINTERS *pt )
{
    //  might create the crash dump....
    MessageBox( NULL, L"ENFIN", L"", 0 );
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}


int WINAPI _tWinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPTSTR, int)
{

    try
    {
        Application->Initialize();
        Application->MainFormOnTaskBar = true;
        Application->CreateForm(__classid(TForm1), &Form1);
        Application->Run();
    }
    __except( Filter( GetExceptionCode(), GetExceptionInformation() ) )
    {
        //  Some code to clear
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I don't want to use external libs such as EurekaLog or MadExcept.

Is anyone has an idea how to prevent the VCL from catching all of the exception ?

Thanks.

Comment: Here's a good article on the subject: http://www.audacia-software.de/en/bcb/external-exception-eefface.htm

Comment: You'll also need to handle the TApplication::OnException event.

Comment: @SamuliHynönen why not a regular answer? I'll be happy to [+1] it. Your link is an interesting read :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, an automated mapping between VCL and STL is a very big deal.

The solution described in [Translate C++ Exceptions to VCL Exceptions](http://www.respower.com/~earlye/programming/TranslateStandardExceptions.htm) causes two hierarchies of logic to be managed, so you will have to catch both `EOutOfRange` and `CppStdOutOfRange` if you don't know if the called implementation is VCL or STL... And it's also error prone as the frameworks may evolve.

My advice is to catch every "expectable" "foreign" exception very early and translate it into the appropriate exception of the the **one exception hierarchy** of your choice: Make sure that all exception classes (that will actually "fly" through your application) inherit (mostly indirectly) from **one base class**.

One important point that you may have forgotten is, as Hans Passant mentioned, to catch not only the application setup exception (as you currently do), but also the runtime exceptions (i.e. all exceptions thrown within the call of the method **`TApplication::Run`**). This can only be done by assigning the event `Application->OnException` - re-read the docs concerning how to do that technically.

**My warm suggestion for a reasonable global exception handler** is to show *and log* a message, then terminate the application. Or even better in this order:

- log the message
- store it to a global buffer
- leave Run by calling `Application->Terminate`
- display the message box in main

a modal message box will keep your poisoned program running - and you don't really know what it does.

Comment: I'm aware about the Application->OnException event but it's not the best way cause it doesn't provide the full exception context so I can't create a minidump to create a detailed crash dump. To do so, we must patch C++ Builder/Delphi source files, before it calls the app's exception handler and then we still have access to the exception's full context. I managed to do so but the patch might be different for each release of delphi.

Comment: @A.G. Ok, you asked about *catching* an exception, that's why I assumed a higher level approach. Having a stack dump is of course great...

Comment: Sorry I didn't made myself clear enough. When I said I didn't want to use external libs such as madexcept and eurekalog it means "I would like to do the same".

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there's no straightforward way to achieve what you want. Here's an interesting article that provides information on the subject and explores some possible solutions: http://www.audacia-software.de/en/bcb/external-exception-eefface.htm